npm install failed in expo react native project on MacOs M1
I was trying to install a package in expo React Native project without success. Based on some recommendations from related, I deleted node_modules folder and then tried running npm install to install all packages in the package.json. Unfortunately, running the npm install command fails with following error message:
npm error code Unknown system error -86
npm error syscall spawn
npm error errno -86
npm error spawn Unknown system error -86
npm error code Unknown system error -86
npm error syscall spawn
npm error errno -86
npm error spawn Unknown system error -86

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/belloshehu/.npm/_logs/2024-07-14T09_59_17_510Z-debug-0.log```


I am using Mac with M1 chip. Please what could be the problem? I am stuck for many hours. 


After reading the system generated log file, I discovered the error was in package.json file caused by erroneous attempt to install a package.
I remove the package name from dependencies inside the package.json and ran the following commands:
sudo npm cache clean --force
sudo npm install
